# Setting Label / TextBox HorizontalContentAlignment not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I've got a composite control with two parts - a label and a value. I've defined a dependency property called "ValueAlignment" which is supposed to set the horizontal alignment of the text in the value part of the control. No matter what I do though, the alignment is defaulting to left. Here's two examples:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I've defined several custom dependency properties, such as LabelWidth and ValueWidth. These work fine, but not the alignment. Dependency properties are defined on the OmniBox object as:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueAlignmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ValueAlignment", typeof(HorizontalAlignment), typeof(OmniBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(HorizontalAlignment.Stretch));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LabelWidth", typeof(String), typeof(OmniBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((String)"40*"));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ValueWidth", typeof(String), typeof(OmniBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((String)"60*"));
etc...

    public HorizontalAlignment ValueAlignment
    {
        get { return (HorizontalAlignment)GetValue(ValueAlignmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueAlignmentProperty, value); }
    }
```

Note that HorizontalContentAlignment has the type `HorizontalAlignment` as defined by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment.aspx). In my control's xaml, I have a predefined set of templates that correspond to different control types for displaying the bound data, and these refer to a set of common pre-defined styles. Here is everything related to the "Limit Load" control above:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:OmniBox}"  x:Key="OBTextBoxTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="PART_Grid" Style="{StaticResource GridStyle}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=LabelWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=ValueWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="PART_Label" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="PART_Value" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="GridStyle" TargetType="Grid" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseElement}">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseValueStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource BoxedValueMargin}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource BoxedValuePadding}" />
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="{Binding Path=ReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=ValueAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:OmniBox}}}" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Control" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseElement}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="BaseElement" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="15" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
</Style>
```

As you can see, the rubber meets the road when I try to bind the HorizontalContentAlignment of the styled textbox to the OmniBox.ValueAlignment dependency property:

`<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=ValueAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:OmniBox}}}" />`

I've also tried the simpler version:

`<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=ValueAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />`

but neither is working. Note that other things in the control template are styled by binding to the TemplatedParent custom property, such as the column widths in the Control Template, and the Text property in the TextBox style, but while those work, the horizontal content alignment doesn't. Can anyone see what I've missed that's causing this not to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the TextBox's **HorizontalContentAlignment** property strangely does nothing at all. One must set the **TextAlignment** property. Of course, because my ValueAlignment dependency property is of the type `HorizontalAlignment`, I need a converter. (I can't change the dependency property type, because other OmniBox control templates use controls like Label which do support the HorizontalContentAlignment property).

I made a simple converter:

```
public class HorizontalTextAlignConverter : BaseConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if( value is HorizontalAlignment )
        {
            switch( (HorizontalAlignment)value )
            {
                case HorizontalAlignment.Center:
                    return TextAlignment.Center;
                case HorizontalAlignment.Left:
                    return TextAlignment.Left;
                case HorizontalAlignment.Right:
                    return TextAlignment.Right;
                case HorizontalAlignment.Stretch:
                    return TextAlignment.Justify; //Arbitrary
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("This converter is intended to convert HorizontalAlignment to TextAlignment and vice versa.");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And then changed up my style binding a tad:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseValueStyle}">
    ...
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="{Binding Path=ValueAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={converters:HorizontalTextAlignConverter}}" />
</Style>
```

And suddenly, everything was magically delicious:
[image]

Phew. That took way too long to figure out.